# Repairing stripped frame split link thread

Tags: cross-thread

I have a steel frame belt driven bike I've very annoyingly stripped one of the female threads on the frame split link which is on the seat stay.

The stripped female thread is for an M5 bolt.  I tried just tapping with an M5 tap but that didn't work.  I have several options available and not sure which is best:

1. Use JB Weld and then tap again with M5.  I've no idea whether this will be strong enough for my application though - anyone know?
2. Re-tap the hole for an M6 bolt after drilling with a 5mm drill.  However, I am not 100% sure I have enough clearance to fit an M6 bolt head the way it nestles into the seat stay.  It's possibly right on the edge as far as I can measure it and so don't want to drill/tap M6 unless there's no better option.
3. Re-tap the hole with a UNC #12-24.  The chart I have says this needs a 4.65mm drill.  Would this work with my M5 hole, which would have been drilled to 4.2mm and then tapped to 5.0mm outer diameter? Or is this unlikely to produce a thread that can hold well?  Would I need to drill or could I just run the tap as is?
4. Use an M5 helicoil repair kit.  This would need a 5.2mm drill bit and so if I go down this route I will close the door to the M6 option.  My concern with this is that the bolt screws into the seat stay such that the bolt is horizontal to the ground.  As a result of the seat stay being at an angle, the exit of the screw hole is also angled.  Not quite sure what would happen to the helicoil given this angled exit?

I've only got one shot at this (well maybe the JB weld route doesn't close any doors) so want to make sure I get it right first time.  I'd be very grateful for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Any chance to just drill through and put a nut on the other side? Or solder the bolt in place and use a split belt for the belt drive?

Answer (score 6):

Using JB Weld or other epoxies to replace lost sections of thread will generally not be strong enough for something like a load-bearing frame member. There are various products made for this kind of repair. Having used several I have a low opinion of any of them necessarily being strong enough to last indefinitely on a load-bearing part of a bike. There might be something out there that can do it but the problem is trusting it in use; if it were to fail, suddenly the left seatstay is doing the work of both and probably at a highly loaded moment, and you could ruin the frame and/or crash.

If you were to try a build-up-and-retap method, brazing in some brass globs and tapping that would probably be the most reasonable.

Between tapping it M6 or using an M5 helicoil, the big constraining factor with either is whether there will be enough material left in the stay after doing the enlargement. The M6 bolt OD is about 5.95mm and the M5 helical insert is about 6.5mm, so if there's barely enough material than going M6 could have that advantage. If the original bolt was a common M5 socket cap bolt with a 4mm wrench fitting, and you decided to tap it M6, you could probably solve the bolt head clearance problem by getting a M6 button head bolt with a 4mm wrench fitting, chucking the bolt into a drill and taking down the sides against a grinder, belt sander, or sandpaper.

If I understand right, the concern with the exit angle is that there's a cutaway section of thread due to the angle, ie the thread is running horizontal even though the stay runs at an angle. What I would look at there is whether there's enough continuous section to get in at least an unadulterated 5mm long insert, so that you can still be sticking to the rule of thumb of at least as much thread engagement as the diameter of the thread. If so you could bypass the cutaway part, which probably isn't doing much to provide grip anyway. I would avoid installing the insert in a way where the outside of the coil is visible due to the cutaway.

In deciding what to do, it bears considering whether it seems like the original design was lacking, perhaps in a way that lead to the failure, and if so whether each option will make that better or worse.

Comment: Many thanks Nathan - this is incredibly helpful.  What about the #12-24 option?  Do you think that could work? It's the one which seems lowest risk to me assuming the thread geometries are not against it working?

Comment: @Stephan Intuitively it strikes me that if enough material has been stripped out already such that you're at this point, then going with something so similar in size might be problematic - again bearing in mind that what you need is a repair that you can trust in use, no crossed fingers. That said, if you can do it that way and be left with clean threads then yes it's probably a good plan as long as trying it first lets you keep the other options in reserve.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with the M5 helicoil as per Nathan's answer.

If you have concerns on your own abilities, there is absolutely nothing wrong with sending the frame to the local bike shop to do the work.    That way they own the risk, and you simply pay for their expertise.

Consider the design of your bike too - it may be prudent to helicoil the other bolt that holds in your seatstay segment before it goes bad.

As an aside - try and figure out how the thread stripped in the first place.  You might choose to use a torque wrench on this fitting in the future, though a helicoil will give you steel threads which are more robust than aluminum ones.

Comment: That last one is easy - the long section of the seat stay wasn't aligned with the short section on the other side of the link.  Rather than bend it into alignment I had the bright idea of loosely putting in the link and relying on the threads to do that - I was distracted at the time by my small kids.....  Issue with the bike shop is I can't imagine they do a lot of this - and I think you only get one go before it's new frame time....

Comment: @Stephan Some bike shops are just sellers.  You want to find a LBS that does the real work.  There may only be one in your nearest city and the other box-movers just onsell their work with a markup.   Look for a LBS that has a pillar drill in the workshop.  Or skip the bike shop and go to a light engineering firm or engineering job shop.

Comment: Consider also, @Stephan, asking around at your higher quality LBS for local frame builders. A builder will have the tools & skills to make the repair for you, whether it's filling in with new metal, then drilling & tapping, or making an insert, or even tweaking the alignment of the stays so this doesn't happen again. (If, of course, that's an ongoing issue or just a one-time distraction. Kids... :)